# Searching through an array of objects in node

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, express

I have an array of objects with each object containing the following data: [image]

I have a node route that pulls in a tag and then searches through it. Right now anything I type returns -1. How can I get a modified array if the the tags match a query.

Again, at the moment, anything I type, including a valid tag returns -1.

At that point, I would turn around with the modified array and inject it into the template as you see there.

```
router.get('/search/:tag', function(req, res) {
  const tag = req.params.tag;
  shopify.article.list(86289414)
  .then(function (response) {
    response.reverse();

    index = response.indexOf(response.filter(function(item) {
      return item.tags == tag
  }) )

  console.log(index);

    var data = {
      articles: index.map((article) => {
        return {
          author: article.author,
          id: article.id,
          html: article.body_html,
          tags: article.tags,
          date: moment(article.published_at).format("Do MMM YYYY"),
          slug: article.handle,
        } // return
      }) // map
    } // data

      res.json(data);

  }) // then
    .catch(err => console.log(err) )
});
```

What's a better way of doing this?

Thank you!

P.S. I looked through lodash and couldn't find anything. I am open to a way in lodash.

Comment: Please don't post images of something that really is an object literal. Post it as text.

Comment: `Array.filter()` returns an array. `indexOf(returnedArray)` will always be -1, as the returned array is just a subset of the original array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following code.

```
response = response.filter(function(item) {
     return item.tags.indexOf(tag) > -1;
   });
```